# multiple where conditions with joining

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, where-clause

I am stuck in a problem since long.

I have a table for `orders` of customers, I want to get 4 types of results like

`1st: All orders with status=place`

then `2nd: All orders with status=place and customer is new` (no previous record in order table of this customer),

then `3rd: All orders with status=place and customer have at least 1 order delivered and never returned previous order` ,

then `4th: All orders with status=place and customer have atleast 1 order with status=returned`

Query for 1st step is working fine, but i got no idea to get other results.I know its like an assignment but i need help.

**MY Try for 1st step**

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.customer_id, o.order_status_id, 
FROM `order` o  
WHERE (o.order_status_id = '1' 
AND o.payment_code <> 'paytabs' 
AND o.payment_code <> 'pp_express') 
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

This give me perfect result for step one.I am using OpenCart 2.2.0.0

**Database Structure**

```
|order_id |status | payment_code |customer_id |
|---------|-------|--------------|------------|
| 10      | place | cod          |   5        |
| 11      | delvr | cod          |   4        |
| 12      | return| pp_express   |   5        |
| 13      |process| paytabs      |   2        |
```

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.
Ask me for anything you need more.

Comment: Avoid right joins - they are quite unusual in the real world.

Comment: ok.. i will use left join in it also...

Comment: any suggestions for others 3 results... please

Comment: I am not clear on how your DB hangs together - Do you have a customer table,what role does order_history play, what do your tables look like , why do you ask for All orders with status=place and test for 'place', what is that complex on statement doing. It would help if you added sampled data and expected result as text to the question.

Comment: updated...now see the query sir...

Comment: Please provide more detail of the DB structure. How is an order identified as "delivered" or "returned" Or are "order" and "customer" the only relevant tables in the DB?

Comment: updated ...check now sir

Comment: I don't get sample data structure in that there is no apparent way of tracking an order's status. Is for example the return for customer 5 (order_id = 12) related  to the order placed for customer 5(order_id = 10) , or are they not related at all and you are only holding the CURRENT status?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure to understand your DB structure, but I will try...

Ad 2:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.customer_id, o.order_status_id, 
FROM `order` o 
WHERE (o.order_status_id = '1' 
AND o.payment_code <> 'paytabs' 
AND o.payment_code <> 'pp_express') 
AND o.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT o2.customer_id from order o2 WHERE o2.order_id != o.order_id AND o2.customer_id = o.customer_id)
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

Accordingly, ad 4:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.customer_id, o.order_status_id, 
FROM `order` o 
WHERE (o.order_status_id = '1' 
AND o.payment_code <> 'paytabs' 
AND o.payment_code <> 'pp_express') 
AND o.customer_id IN (SELECT o2.customer_id from order o2 WHERE o2.order_status = 'returned')
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

Now for 3:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.customer_id, o.order_status_id, 
FROM `order` o 
WHERE (o.order_status_id = '...?') 
AND o.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT o2.customer_id from order o2 WHERE o2.order_status = 'returned')
AND o.customer_id IN (SELECT o3.customer_id from order o3 WHERE o3.order_status = 'delivered')
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

BTW: I strongly recommend to rename table "order" since "order" is an SQL keyword.

Comment: my table full name is `a6x9_order` , i am using prefixes for all tables

Comment: I've tried for 3rd step and it works... i will apply all one by one and then sum all results ..if i get accurate sum, my energy will be doubled ...sir

Comment: @MoizAhmad: Just for my curiosity - are the other SQL statements working for you as well?

Comment: Yes Sir, I am grateful to you for your help... Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Union when you want to do that with one query.

Other ways, when same customer meets 2 contidions, then you will only see one.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0):

For the 2nd query : you can just add an AND clause to your SQL :
AND user_id = 0

Assuming a new order is inserted with user_id = 0 if this is a new user

Answer (score 0):

queries:
the queries are as per your question u asked and you orders table structure(i am considering that you have not created any column like created_at and updated_at).

1. select * from orders where status = 'place';
2. select orders.order_id ,orders.customer_id from orders where status = 'place' GROUP BY order_id, customer_id HAVING COUNT(customer_id) = 1;
3. select a.order_id, a.customer_id from orders a where a.status in (select b.status from orders b where a.order_id = b.order_id and status <> 'return') and a.status = 'place' GROUP BY a.order_id, a.customer_id HAVING COUNT(a.customer_id) >= 1;
4. select a.order_id, a.customer_id from orders a where a.status in (select b.status from orders b where a.order_id = b.order_id and status = 'return') and a.status = 'place' GROUP BY a.order_id, a.customer_id HAVING COUNT(a.customer_id) >= 1

Comment: can you provide me structure of both the tables customers and orders.